# How to check for integer repetitions in a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I am trying to do problem no.5 from Project Euler, which reads: 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20? I am first trying to calculate for numbers 1-10, and then I will move to 1-20.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector <int> nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

bool isPrime(unsigned int num)
{
    if (num <= 2)
        return true;

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        return false;

    unsigned sqr = (unsigned)sqrt(num);
    for (unsigned i = 3; i <= sqr; i += 2) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void LowestMultiple(vector<int> nums) {
    for (vector< int>::iterator it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++) {
        if (isPrime(*it)) {
            cout << *it << endl;
        }
        else {
            int m = *it;
            int minit = *it;
            std::vector<unsigned int> pfactors;
            if (m % 2 == 0) {
                do {
                    m /= 2;
                } while (m % 2 == 0);
                pfactors.push_back(2);
            }

            for (int i = 3; i <= m; i += 2) {
                if (m % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
                    do {
                        m /= i;
                    } while (m % i == 0);
                    pfactors.push_back(i);
                }
            }
            for (vector<unsigned  int>::iterator it2 = pfactors.begin(); it2 !=       pfactors.end(); it2++) {
                cout << minit << ":" << *it2 << endl;
            }
        }
    }


}

int main() {
    LowestMultiple(nums);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I created a vector that contains all the prime factors of numbers 1-10, and now I need to find how many times each prime factor is repeated in the vector and then multiply the prime factors the according number of times in order to get the LCM. How can I do that? Is there a more efficient algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: Does your current code now work? If no, where does it fail? If yes, try on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you are looking for improvements.

Comment: @FirstStep it does work, but I don't know what to do further (how to check for integet iterations in a vector).

Answer (score 1):

The result of the question is the LCM of [1,10]

> LCM of 2 numbers lcm(a,b) = (a*b)/GCD(a,b) where GCD = Greatest Common Divisor

```
typedef long long ll;

ll gcd(ll a,ll b){
    if(!b)
        return a;
    else return gcd(b,a%b);
}

int main(){

    ll ans  = 1,N= 10;

    for(ll i = 2;i < N; ++i)
        ans = (ans * i)/gcd(ans,i);

    cout<<ans<<"\n";        
}
```

Comment: And is gcd() a built-in function?

Comment: **typedef** is used to create alias to a datatype. gcd() is not a built in function i've written it above main() function